# Selecting option in select field does not trigger ajax script in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

Triggering ajax response doesn't work in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer when selecting an option in the  field. It does work in all other browsers though.

Here's the html:

```
<select>
  <option class="showDiv" data-div="0,1,0,mw1,default" data-vars="2136,1|10|1|0" selected="">added</option>
  <option class="showDiv" data-div="0,1,0,mw1,default" data-vars="2136,1|10|1|1">title</option>
  </select>
```

And here's the ajax part:

```
$('.showDiv').live("click", function () {
    var divs = $(this).attr('data-div');
    var vars = $(this).attr('data-vars');
    divs = divs.split(",");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "crt/run_script.php",
        data: {
            divs: divs,
            vars: vars,
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            centerWin("loading");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading").hide("fast");
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $("#mainWin").html('');
            $("#mainWin").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of Chrome, IE, and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Chrome the latest version. IE 8 (not because I want to, but because it has to work on IE 8 :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing that why don't you do on change of the select element?

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
   ...
});
```

---

To get the option that is selected you can just do this:

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
   var index = this.selectedIndex;
   var option = $(this.options[index]);
   //rest of the code use `option` instead of `this` in your code
   ...
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't know how to rewrite the code so that it uses your suggestion

Comment: @mick_smick i added how to do it.

Comment: Great. You rock. I've changed my script to:
    $('.showSelect').live(
      "change",function(){
      var index = this.selectedIndex;
      var option = $(this.options[index]);
         
      var divs = $(option).attr('data-div');
      ...

and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work in IE :(. But at least it works in Chrome :).

Comment: @mick_smick get the data attributes like this: `$(option).data('div')`...etc. do not get it with `attr(...)`

Comment: I did this var divs = $(option).data('div'); and still nothing

Comment: @mick_smick -- in any browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3422/discussion-between-mick-smick-and-neal)